# How do you close a VMWare Fusion VM Window without shutting it down or suspending it?

Tags: command-line, vmware-fusion

There are a few parts to this question.

The first is:
I'm running a virtual machine guest using vmrun and nogui, when I open the VMWare Fusion application, the window library opens but subsequently also opens any window of a running VM. Is there a way to prevent this?

Secondly, but related:
Once it does pop up or I have that separate VM Window open, is there a way to close the window such that it does not suspend or shutdown the vm i.e. convert it back to nogui mode?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Victor, but I'm unfortunately not looking for snapshots. Good info though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried it yet, but it seems like [this answer on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98473) might be what you're looking for:

> An additional way, you can start up the VMs you want and then force quit VMware Fusion using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>
>
> The GUI quits but the VMs run in the background. To manage these VMs you can start VMware fusion again as usual and it will show you what's currently running.

Answer (score 11):

There is a better way (at least with Fusion 8)

VMware Fusion > Preferences and tick the "Confirm before closing" checkbox.

[image]

Now, when you close a GUI window, you will receive a prompt with buttons for Poweroff, Suspend, etc... You will also see a button to "Run in Background" which will close the GUI window but, leave the VM running in the background.

Comment: This also works in v7. Tested on v7.1.3